# Discord Bot - Cannot access FLAGS from Intents

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I started coding personal bot. I'm getting an error

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'FLAGS')

I'm assuming it can't access FLAGS. I don't understand why because I have installed the latest node and discord.js. I allowed all premission for 'Privileged Gateway Intents' for my Bot on my personal account on Discord Developer Portal. I followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qc9uPgGmQ7I

This is my code so far:

```
require("dotenv").config();
const { Client, Intents } = require("discord.js")
const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES
  ]
});

client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on("interactionCreate", async interaction => {
  if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;

  if (interaction.commandName === "ping") {
    await interaction.reply("Pong!");
  }
});

client.login(process.env.SPELL_BOT_TOKEN)
```

Comment: What version of DJS are you using?

Comment: I updated my version of DJS now it's working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means you are using Discord.js v11 or older, where intents weren't there so to update it to v12 or newer you can:

- Reinstall the module with `npm uninstall discord.js` and `npm install discord.js`.
- Update it to the latest version with `npm install discord.js@dev` or a specific one with `npm install discord.js@13.3.1`.
- Edit the version of the module in your `package.json` file.

Comment: This helped me. Now it's working like charm. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

the first mistake I see is that you have to pass object to Client class, you did `new Client(intents: [...]})`. should be like `new Client({ intents: [...] })`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you, I corrected that. Neverthless, there still error. I will try what @Leau suggested even though I have the latest Discord.js .

Comment: I also edited the code in the post so if someone copies the code they hopefully don't get the error.